# Can't Open Trash In Lubuntu (PCManFM)

Tags: lubuntu, trash

There is no `Trash` available in `Places` (The left side shortcuts in PCManFM) and if I try to go to `trash:///` it says `Operation not supported`

I am running Lubuntu Desktop 16.04 on my server and my Xstartup file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey -cursor_name left_ptr
autocutsel -fork
lxsession -s Lubuntu -e LXDE
```

Note: It works all good when I'm `root` but as a `sudo user` it doesn't.